# Dataset problems in landslide suscetibility assessment with python ML algorithms

Tags: python, dataset, geo

hope you all are doing fine :)

To contextualize my problem, I'm a non-programmer guy who is trying to do some python codes to assess landslide suscetibility. I'm trying to do it by applying a Naive-Bayes machine learning Algorithm to a huge dataset.

Considering this, here is the first explanation of what my dataset looks like.

In the imagem below, The left map is an ALOS PALSAR Digital Elevation Model - DEM (a satellite image where one pixel equals to 12.5x12.5m);
The red dots are mapped landslides and the pink ones are random points located in areas where it is confirmed to be a safe area, where no landslides has occurred. From the DEM I've extracted the Height, Slope, Curvature, Topographic Wetness Index (TWI) and Litology (not in the tables yet).
[DEM and extracted information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xODK3.jpg)

From this extraction I got the table below, with approximately 650 points (With certain X, Y positions each). This is my first dataset, from which I intend to use to "teach" the algorithm, since it have about 330 points with landslides = 1 and about 330 points with landslide = 0.
[Dataset/table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ytz.jpg)

Well, here comes my problem. I need to make my algorithm train with the dataset above and apply it to a whole new dataset extracted from the DEM previously cited. The resultant table from the new extraction has no "landslide" values, altough it have the same information as the first dataset, as confirmed in the next image.[Dataset that needs to be predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22maB.jpg)

In this table, we have every pixel from the DEM (±6.200.000) with their singles features and positions. The column "landslide" must be assigned with a 0/1 value through the python algorithm, and then imported back in the ArcMap software to generate an Landslide suscetibility map.

I've been watching some youtube videos (like codebasics or some other paid digital schools) and I learned to make a prediction considering the first dataset. Here's the code i'm using.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset1 = pd.read_csv("dataset_name.csv")
dv = base2.iloc[:,3:7] #dependent_variables
iv = base2.iloc[:,7] #independent_variable

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dv_train, dv_test, iv_train, iv_test = train_test_split(dv, iv, test_size=0.30, random_state=0)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianN
classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(dv_train, iv_train)
predictions = classifier.predict(dv_train)
```

I have translated the variables in this code from my native lenguage to english, so it might no work properly due to some errors along the way. The thing is, I managed to make an antire column of predictions out of my dataset1, with the exact amount of lines of my train split. I done this considering that I have the known 0/1 values for landslide columns, and I have no idea how to apply or how to use this training in the huge 6.2kk lines one.

This is my question: How do I apply this code to my second dataset? How do I elaborate this code?

Thanks everyone. I'm also avaliable for further questions and to give more detailed info about this project.